# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

народ, помогите решить данную ошибку, пожалуйста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска появляется ошибка TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 0,15 - это два числа (tuple по сути). В Python (и большинстве других языков программирования) для разделения целой и дробной части используется точка.

Comment: пробовал `x <= 5` если не работает, то не знаю.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = 5
x = x + 0,15
print(x)
(5, 15)
```

Это если использовать запятую

```
x = 5
x = x + 0.15
print(x)
5.15
```

А это если точку. Еще советую такие операции записывать следующим видом

```
х = 5 
x += 0.15
print(x)
5.15
```